# Were the duration of Bachelor's, Master's and PhD degrees different in the U.S. 100 years ago?

Tags: united-states, education, academic-history

Given that there were much less to learn 100 years ago, was the duration of degrees shorter then than it is now?

Comment: Actually there was never "much less to learn". People just learned different things than now. Lots of things that Henri Poincaré learned, you don't need to learn. In fact, 100,000 years ago, humans had the same mental facilities that we do. But they had different concerns and so learned different things. How to hunt Woolly Mammoth, for example. No degree programs then, I suspect.

Comment: From my alumni magazine, a bachelors was 4 years then, still 4 years now. A masters was 1 or 2 years, same as today. It would seem that PhDs in, say, physics, were somewhat shorter on average (3-5 years, not 5-7ish). Why? Hard to say for sure.

Comment: @JonCuster, even 60 years ago, you could earn a doctorate post bachelors in 4 years. It was pretty much standard. I'd have done it had I had a more helpful advisor. But I had a grant, so didn't need to TA.

Comment: @Buffy - indeed, directly doing a PhD after a bachelors was doable in 4 years in many fields. It is kind of unclear just why things have lengthened, but part of it might be that the demand for PhDs was not being met by the supply (in general).

Comment: Hard to say, exactly. There were lots of TAs back then and they may have taken longer than 4. But in some fields, it might have been a ramp up in demand and more students meant that less accessible research problems had to be introduced. Harder problems so longer to find solutions. There was a lot going on in math back then. New fields opening. New ways of thought. I don't know of any research on this.

Comment: Thee may even have been an effect that an influx of new faculty meant less experience on average so more likely that their students wouldn't get the help that the previous (smaller) generation had.

Comment: @Buffy - I'm on the physics/materials side, and I can recall several examples of people getting a PhD in ~4 years, publishing perhaps one or two papers, becoming a professor at a major university, and having a long, if not well published, career afterwards. Certainly post-war there was a large demand to staff up. Pre-war there just weren't really that many PhDs being awarded.

Comment: Don't forget the moon program and the [NDEA funding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Defense_Education_Act). It ended when we beat the "Ruskies" to the moon.

Comment: In the UK, all PhD have a 4 year time limit...

Comment: "*there were much less to learn 100 years ago*" doesn't make sense. In the last 100 years there has been a lot of knowledge added to what is known, so in theory at least, there was actually *more* to learn 100 years ago.  But in practice, the amount of unknown knowledge that PhD students can discover was, and is, effectively infinite.

Comment: Interesting question, but the scope is too broad.  In Australia, the first PhDs was awarded in 1948.  So, yes, the degrees offered were different 100 years ago.  Maybe narrow down to a single country?  Many countries have seen changes owing to Bologna process.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_Process

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S., the Ph.D. is longer now on average, especially in the sciences because of the influx of money for paid research, the use of grad students to do research, professors as almost pure managers and grant funders versus real working scientists, etc. It has become something like Renaissance painting done by subordinates.  Except I still think the painters got their hands dirty and gave instruction.

There is almost no apprenticeship in R1 science from the professor, just other students and perhaps post docs. It is essentially about milking the grad student for results to get more grants, travel, promotions, grow the empire, etc.  Thus the expectation for work product has gone up.  Add onto that, that the money has enabled way more actual Ph.D.s to exist, but not increased the number of geniuses in the population and fundamental advances are if anything harder as simple much of the low hanging fruit is plucked.  And you have a situation of volume of result being emphasized.  Not the trainee education.

And enjoy the job market at the end...

All that said, if you sniff around you can find profs or even departments that still emphasize the classic 4 years.  But you will have to search. It is abnormal now.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that on average these degrees take longer now, so yes, they would be shorter back then. Why do I say this? Because today there are many students who might take internships for a year, many students take longer because of more distractions available to them, more institutions exist now, and because supervisors typically have substantially more administrative tasks they are responsible for now suggests that it’s more likely supervisors also have less time now to give to their graduate students then they did 100 years ago.

I don’t know if “there’s so much more to learn now” is as solid as the reasons that I have suggested. Yes, there is more to learn, but it doesn’t mean everything is relevant to learn. We also have tools to significantly boost our productivity in order to manage that intense growth of knowledge (think how much just one computer screen can boost productivity, let alone 2-3 of them).

These reasons, among others, are probably factors that would contribute to longer graduation times.